# microsoft azure file upload api creation in javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-blob-storage, azure-static-website-hosting

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/browser-file-upload-azure-storage-blob

I used this sample repo and was following the step by step procedure given in this website. I got stuck at point no-9. Can anyone help me with the same by providing me screenshot of every step after 9th.
(Where is azure explorer and what to do after going to source control [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp0b5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9afP.png)

Till point no-8 its working fine but I am unable to understand what to do after 8

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

The step is to **`Deploy static web app to Azure`**.
In visual studio you need to sign in with azure subscription by left side panel clicking Azure symbol you can be able to add to your subscription by signing in.

[image]

After signing in click, the resource **`+`** symbol and create static web app.

[image]

To create enter your static app name, resource group, SKU, default project structure-react, location of your application code-/appname, path of your build output- Build, location for new resources-location you needed. After creation you will get notification in bottom like in document.

The 10th step is adding our azure storage secrets to github secrets:

```
https://github.com/YOUR-GITHUB-ACCOUNT/js-e2e-browser-file-upload-storage-blob/settings/secrets/actions
```

[image]

Add the two secrets and their values by creating new repository secret with name and secret.

Once you set the secrets in your visual studio code `.github/workflows` workflow add the two environment variables.

```
 env: # Add environment variables here
            REACT_APP_STORAGESASTOKEN: ${{secrets.REACT_APP_STORAGESASTOKEN}}
            REACT_APP_STORAGERESOURCENAME: ${{secrets.REACT_APP_STORAGERESOURCENAME}}
```

By clicking the Synchronize changes symbol in the status bar, you can push to your GitHub fork.

[image]

Now you can deploy in web sites by clicking browse sites.

[image]

You can now upload the image and using static web site.

[image]

**Reference:**
[JavaScript: Upload image to Blob Storage - Azure | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/browser-file-upload-azure-storage-blob)

Comment: When I press on create static web app it says error occurred and on output.. 6:06:07 pm: Error: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'SubscriptionTreeItem'
    |     property 'parent' -> object with constructor 'AzureAccountTreeItem'
    |     property '_cachedChildren' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    --- index 0 closes the circle

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/education/codespaces-project-template-js/issues/13